# Populate drop down using PHP ODBC function

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, odbc

Can you help me tracing my problem on populating drop down menu using ODBC Function in PHP. Here's my code:

```
$conn = $conn = odbc_connect("mm370lib", "ictapps", "s3cur3344");
    if(! $conn){
        print( "Cannot connect to database" );
        exit;
    }

    $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM APSUPP";
    //$res = odbc_do($conn, $qry);
    $res1 = odbc_exec($conn, $qry1);
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='vendor_name'>";

    while($row1 = odbc_fetch_row($res1)){
        echo "<option value='".$row1["ASNUM"]."'>".$row1["ASNAME"]."</option>";
    }
    odbc_free_result($res1);
    echo "</select>";
```

It is not showing the fetch data from database.

[See attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfoD1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc, `odbc_fetch_row()` does not return a row, but just `true` or `false`, indicating if a row was fetched. See here for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-row.php

So, following the doc, you need to call `odbc_result()` after you've fetched a row. See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result.php

It should probably be something like this (I do not have a php environment here right now, so this code is untested):

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($res1))
{
    $asnum = odbc_result($res1, "ASNUM");
    $asname = odbc_result($res1, "ASNAME");
    echo "<option value='".$asnum."'>".$asname."</option>";
}
```